# Calling parameterized methods from facelet, jsf

Tags: jsf

I have a nested  from which I would like to call a method on my bean, passing the current object in iteration.

This method would turn that object into a HTML representation of that complex object. How do I call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a function in facelets-taglib with signature:

```
<function-signature>java.lang.String getMyHTMLFor (com.company.MyComplexObject)</function-signature>
```

then called it in my facelet:

```
<c:forEach items=#{grouping} var="object">
  <f:verbatim>
    #{mySchemaPrefix:getMyHTMLFor(object)}
  </f:verbatim>
</c:forEach>
```